# Unity - Get random Skybox out of array

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, skybox

For a school task I have to make a basic video game.
I am trying to make a basic version of a space game.

I want an array with multiple skyboxes in it and, when launching the game, I want the game to choose a random Skybox out of the array. That way you will have the feeling that you are in a different spawnlocation everytime.

Can anyone help me? I have been looking on google but I cannot find anything helpful.

The skyboxes are located in a folder named:

- 'Assets/SkyBox Volume 2/DeepSpaceBlue' file name = DSB
- 'Assets/SkyBox Volume 2/DeepSpaceGreen' file name = DSG
- ...

This is my current code and it contains errors.

**EDIT**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class RandomSkybox : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Material[] materials;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        skyBoxMaterial = materials[Random.Range(0, materials.length)];
        RenderSettings.skybox = skyBoxMaterial;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0103  The name 'skyBoxMaterial' does not exist in the current context SpaceRaiders.CSharp D:\Documenten\Unity\SpaceRaiders\Assets\Scripts\Space\RandomSkybox.cs   10  Active
Error   CS1061  'Material[]' does not contain a definition for 'length' and no extension method 'length' accepting a first argument of type 'Material[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   SpaceRaiders.CSharp D:\Documenten\Unity\SpaceRaiders\Assets\Scripts\Space\RandomSkybox.cs   10  Active
Error   CS0103  The name 'skyBoxMaterial' does not exist in the current context SpaceRaiders.CSharp D:\Documenten\Unity\SpaceRaiders\Assets\Scripts\Space\RandomSkybox.cs   11  Active
```

Comment: See this : http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/541258/load-material-texture-from-file.html

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ .. OP's problem is just that he forgot to drag in

Comment: @JoeBlow yes.. if he was to populate it by code, the link would have been helpful..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public Skybox[] skyBoxes;
```

you have to

## drag the items to the array

it's that simple.  In the **Inspector**, set the length to say "5", and then drag your five items in.  Nothing more to it.

---

Also in the latest version you have posted,

```
skyBoxMaterial = materials[Random.Range(0, materials.length)];
```

You forgot to declare the variable.  it's that simple.

```
Material skyBoxMaterial;
skyBoxMaterial = materials[Random.Range(0, materials.length)];
```

---

for "length" obviously it "Length".  Don't forget for List<> it is `.Count` not `.Length`.

Comment: It's not working because the code is wrong, I am editting my post

Comment: I'm now still getting this error, thanks for the help!

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'Material[]' does not contain a definition for 'length' and no extension method 'length' accepting a first argument of type 
'Material[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) SpaceRaiders.CSharp D:\Documenten\Unity\SpaceRaiders\Assets\Scripts\Space\RandomSkybox.cs 11 Active